# nat and xen, nat only to external ip

Tags: iptables, nat, xen

I've setup xen that way that all my vm's have a public ip and a private ip (192.168.0.x).

However, those vms which don't have a puplic ip should also get internet access so I did setup nat.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

But when I add this rule to iptables I'm no longer able to ping the other vm's on their private ip's, only the dom0 which has 192.168.0.1.

Is it possible to NAT only if the destination address is not on the 192.168.0.x network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just add `! -d 192.168.0.0/24` to the `iptables` command you list above.  It's more common to restrict `MASQUERADE` by outgoing interface (eg `-o eth0`) instead, though.